# Apache for php working locally but not globally - Windows

Tags: php, apache, server

I have been at this for a while thought I would seek some help before I hit the sack. I have successfully downloaded Apache on a windows server and can run PHP files locally on that server. Using the IP Address when I run :

**http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8085/test.php**

on my local machine, I get a webpage error.

I checked on the Apache server, port, the IP and all but it yet doesn't seem to work. I am not well versed with servers and have a very brief idea about it.
What could be the issue?

Comment: _"run it outside the server"_ could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: You may have better luck here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Was trying to say that I am trying to open it from a different IP and calling the php file with the server IP.

Comment: Hey Izion! Thanks, shall post my question there. :)

Comment: Your machine doesn't know what `pvtictapptst` is, so your request never reaches the Apache or PHP. `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc`, open `hosts` file, check what's in there and link the name with the appropriate IP. Save the file, then try again. Note: you must open it as an adminstrator.

Comment: Hey! I already have it in the hosts file. I have been working with it since a month (using pvtictapptst) on my machine and never had any issue. This problem started yesterday. It doesn't work even when I specify the IP address of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a solution. The port was blocked on firewall. Just had to add an exception for the port.